# No muestra cambios en Ionic 1

Tags: javascript, ionic, ionic-framework, build

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto desarrollado en Ionic 1 y me encuentro que cuando modifico el código no se aplica ninguno de los cambios realizados.

¿Alguna idea de por que no muestra ninguna modificación?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

deberías de completar un poco más tu pregunta para poder ayudarte al respecto, ya que no entiendo en que esta fallando. Espero poder ayudarte.

Saludos!

Comment: Estoy trabajando con un proyecto realizado en Ionic 1. Cuando intento compilarlo a través del comando "ionic cordova build ios" me lanza el siguiente mensaje, parece que compile de forma correcta pero no aplica ningún cambio.

"[WARN] Not performing Ionic build for project type: ionic1.
> cordova build ios "